# Animation of textfields for not to hide underneth the keboard, behaves differently in simulator and actual device in IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7, uitextfield

In device it scrolls underneath the navigation bar,but in simulator it pops into the navigation bar so navigation bar hides the text field.

/// This is for text field did begin editing.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    CGPoint scrollPoint;
    CGRect inputFieldBounds = [textField bounds];
    inputFieldBounds = [textField convertRect:inputFieldBounds toView:scrollView];
    scrollPoint = inputFieldBounds.origin;
    scrollPoint.x = 0;
    scrollPoint.y -= 30; // you can customize this value
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

//// to get the scrool to the back,i am writing this in textfield should return

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   CGPoint scrollPoint;
   scrollPoint.x = 0;
   scrollPoint.y = 0;// you can customize this value
   [scrollView  setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
//// end
```

Comment: and what would be the difference in behavior?

Comment: In device it scrolls underneath the navigation bar,but in simulator it pops into the navigation bar so navigation bar hides the text field.

Comment: you can try to add in viewWillAppear this code: self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to add in `viewWillAppear` this code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```